# Editing object within arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have code which requires for the original object values to change within an ArrayList. Here is how the code works now, but I do not believe it will change the values for the original object.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pairedSystems.size(); i++) {
        System sys = (System) pairedSystems.get(i);
        if (sys.id() == system.id()) {
            sys.addPower((int) pairedId.get(i), amount);

        }
    }
```

I would like a type of code which would guarantee the retrieved object is modified within the ArrayList. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: return the array list in your method when you're done editing the objects and assign it to the arraylist previously passed in?

Comment: @RAX_Muh_Taz Hmm. That might work. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It's not a new object. You just create a new reference to the existing object so the object will be modified no matter what...

Comment: @YassinHajaj To help me visualize this, is it like if I had one guy with two different names, Bob and Bill, and I wanted to punch the guy, it does not matter if I call him Bob or Bill, and the punch still connects to the same guy?

Comment: @OneSurvivor Yeah. It's like having different controllers to the same television. If you change the channel using one, the channel will change.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Okay, thanks! You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList.set()` to set a value at a given index. After modifying the object, set the object at the index:

`pairedSystems.set(i, sys)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works like a charm.